# can't copy user or role privileges in MySql 8.0

Tags: mysql, database, sql-grant

I've tried this queries in PhpMyAdmin and DataGrip:

```
drop user god_user, god;
create user god_user identified by 'god', god identified by 'god';
grant all on *.* to god with grant option ;
grant god to god_user;

show grants for god_user
```

It seems like all is OK, `show grants for god_user` shows this:

```
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `god_user`@`%`
GRANT `god`@`%` TO `god_user`@`%`
```

And with PhpMyAdmin, I could login as `god` and see that I have `ALL PRIVILEGES` with flag `GRANT` set to `YES`. But what about `god_user`, it shows that there's NO privileges for `god_user`. Why? And if I login into PhpMyAdmin as `god_user`, I can't even see my DBs list!

Is that a bug? It is OK if I `grant all on *.* to god_user with grant option`.

`flush privileges` gives me nothing new. Also if `god` is a `role`, not `user` (I think there's no big difference). I am root.

Comment: When granting one user's privileges to another, don't you need to use the Proxy keyword?

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson, I just needed to activate my roles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was ultra-dumb: I forgot to activate my roles.
The following code fixed my issue. (It activates all granted roles to specified users.)

```
set default role all to god_user, admin;
```

And that's it)

The paragraph about 'activating roles' WAS in documentation, but I skipped it...